# Ошибка из-за которой происходит незапланированый выход из программы

Tags: java, android

Суть в том что:

1. Пользователь нажимает кнопку search, после чего открывается список стран в activity
2. Пользователь выбирает несколько стран
3. После нажатия соответсвующей кнопки в activity отображается средее 
   арифметическое количества населения выбранных стран.

Activity 1 запускается. После нажатия на кнопку Search  происходит незапланированый выход из программы.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

Button button_1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    button_1.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
 }
 }
```

Разметка

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="@string/button_1" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity 2

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

String[] countries = {"Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
int[] population = {6770000, 2300000, 500000, 6310000, 7000000};
Button btnSubmit;
int sum;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2main);

    Map<String, Integer> countryData = new HashMap<>(countries.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        countryData.put(countries[i], population[i]);
        }
        countryData.forEach((key, value) -> 
    System.out.println(key + " -> " 
    + value));

    ListView countriesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.countriesList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);

            countriesList.setAdapter(adapter);

    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++)
    {
        sum += population[i];
    }
    this.sum = sum;

    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("average", sum);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Разметка для activity 2

```
 android:id="@+id/activity_2main"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:id="@+id/countriesList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Submit">
</Button>
```

Activity 3

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvView;
int sum;
int defaultValue = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("average", 0);

    tvView.setText("Your name is: " + sum);
}
}
```

Разметка activity 3

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="20sp">
</TextView>
```

Вот лог

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.***.app1, PID: 2126
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.***.app1.Main2Activity$$Lambda$0
    at com.example.***.app1.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:34)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at 
 android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Что вылетает? Телефон в форточку? Стэктрейс ошибки показывайте. Все активности в манифесте объявлены?

Comment: В `Main2Activity ` вы объвили тип `int sum`. Зачем в onCreate опять объявляете тип? Что по вашему отправляется в интенте `intent.putExtra("average", sum);` ?

Comment: @woesss, обьявлены

Comment: @TimurVI, по-моему, среднее арифметическое

Comment: @TimurVI, я только учусь. Так что обьясните, если что не так

Comment: другими словами -у вас `sum`  в onClick  и в onCreate разный. В onCreate on создается и остается там. в onClick вы передаете объявленную переменную без какого-либо значения. в onCreate уберите int перед sum

Comment: @TimurVI, тогда как будет производиться расчет ?

Comment: у вас до onCreate создается глобальная int sum. В onCreate вы создаете опять int sum не глобальную. в onClick передаете глобальную, которой ничего не присвоили. если в onCreate убрать перед sum "int"? то есть оставить просто sum = 0, и далее ваш цикл, то тогда sum будет той глобальной переменной что была объявлена до onCreate. Тогда в onClick придет sum со значением из onCreate

Comment: @TimurVI, так и не работает. Unfortunately, app has stoped

Comment: Попробуйте убрать строку - `this.sum = sum;`

Comment: @TimurVI, Не работает. Выложил логи

Answer (score 2):

Во второй активности задана разметка для первой:
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
соответственно `ListView` в ней нет и обращение к нему вызывает `NPE`.

По поводу суммы:

```
int sum = 0;
```

Так Вы объявляете локальную переменную, с таким же именем, как у поля `sum`. Она перекрывает это поле и далее по коду до конца метода изменяется именно она, а поле не меняется. То есть Вам нужно не объявлять ещё одну переменную, а использовать существующую или после расчёта присваивать её значение полю:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++) {
    sum += population[i];
}
this.sum = sum;
```

Почитайте в любом учебнике java про область видимости переменных

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); +1

Comment: @woesss, так и не работает. Unfortunately, app has stoped

Comment: Запускаете на Андроид 7.0 или выше? Если нет уберите аннотацию `@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)` и сделайте код совместимым со всеми поддерживаемыми API

Comment: @woesss, тогда на forEach ошибка "call requires api 24..."

Comment: В том-то и дело что на устройстве с версией Андроид меньше 7.0 (api 24) такого метода нет, а Вы это проигнорировали в коде и за это получили ошибку во время исполнения. Вообще в текущем виде этот код просто бесполезный - Вы можете смело его удалить. А если он Вам всё-таки нужен замените на обычный цикл - он работает на всех версиях API.